# Interpreter for Quantities without magnitude

Tags: units, interpreter

When using a quantity interpreter on a unit without magnitude, the interpreter fails, but works fine on quantities with magnitudes.

Ex:

```
Interpreter["Quantity"]["meter"]
```

Out: ERROR

```
Interpreter["Quantity"]["1 meter"]
```

Out: `1m`, as expected.

What I expect:

```
Interpreter["Quantity"]["meter"]
```

Out: `m`

I don't see why the interpreter won't do this.  The only solution I can find for when I have a LIST of magnitude-less quantities is

```
table={"Meter","Feet","Second",etc.}
Interpreter["Quantity"][StringJoin["1 ", #] & /@ table]
```

But that's a silly workaround, and then I can't remove the 1.

Summary:

What I want: **Given a list of (string) units, returns a list of those units in a computational format.**

The problem: Using `Interpreter["Quantity"]["Unit"]` FAILS, while `Interpreter["Quantity"]["1 Unit"]` works.  However, I just want to return `"Unit"`, not `"1 Unit"`.

P.S For anyone interested in my application, I need a list of all units in WL for a CompatibleUnit program I'm making.

So I have

```
table = Keys[QuantityUnits`Private`$UnitReplacementRules]
Interpreter["Quantity"][table]
```

Comment: I am not sure that I understand, however, would `Quantity["meter"]` do what you want? Its `FullForm` is `Quantity[None, "Meters"]`. Notice however that `"meter"` is NOT present as a string in the `table` you generate at the end of your post; `"Meters"` can be found in there instead.

Comment: Not sure if I understand either, so not sure if this does what you want, but `Interpreter[Quantity["meter"]][[1, 2]]` gives `Meters`, and the latter is in a computational format.   E.g., if you set `ans = Interpreter[Quantity["meter"]][[1, 2]]` , then evaluate `UnitConvert[ans, "Feet"]`, you'll get `1250/381 ft`

Comment: @MarcoB, it's not quite what I want, because I want to be able to extend it to when the user doesn't input the exactly correct name; that's why I want to use interpreter.

Note that Interpreter["Quantity"]["meter"] fails.  I don't mind what the FullForm output is.  I just want `Interpreter["Quantity"]["Unit"] to return unit.  However, it fails